# Linear model in R with time as variable

Tags: r, model, large-data

Thank you @Metrics for the answer to the original question.

I want to make a linear model from two variables. My explanatory variable is a time variable. It was in factors so I converted it to POSIXlt, but when I did that R returned the error

```
 Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action =
 na.fail,  :    invalid type (list) for variable 'Time2'
```

How do I make a linear model with time as a variable?

Old Question:
**30,000 Observations and Fitting a Model in R**

I have a dataframe of 36,729 observations. I want to make a model of two variables so that I can work with an equation rather than all those datapoints. For now let us simply seek a linear model.

```
lm(v2~v1,df)
```

Because the large size of the dataframe, though, it seems R (or my computer, perhaps?) cannot handle the command. After an hour of running the command, R still hasn't finished processing it.

What am I to do? Do I just need to wait longer? Is there a way to make the dataframe a lighter load? Is there a package for large amounts of data? (I don't really imagine this scale qualifies as "large amounts of data" but it certainly seems to much for R and/or my computer.)

Comment: I just ran a `lm` on 30.000 random observations and it finished in 0.03 seconds. Is there something else special about your data?

Comment: @Molx Got the same. 0.03 seconds user time.

Comment: Running this: `df <- data.frame(v1=rnorm(36729), v2=rnorm(36729)); system.time(lm(v1~v2, data=df))` gives me 0.03s user time for a problem of this size. Something particular must be going on with your data set.

Comment: Might help to post the output from `str(df[c("v1", "v2")]) ` so we can see if anything looks wrong with the data.

Answer (score 1):

One reason might be (see `str(data)`) that your explanatory variable is a factor variable: See the time difference for a factor explanatory variable and a continuous explanatory variable.

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width,data=iris),lm(Sepal.Length~Species,data=iris),times=1000)
Unit: microseconds
                                        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval cld
 lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width, data = iris)  896.324  948.129 1007.356  976.963 1011.174  2460.735  1000  a 
     lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data = iris) 1106.476 1173.432 1330.917 1211.064 1250.406 45466.654  1000   b
```

Comment: ooh I think that might be it

Comment: Alright, this answer makes sense and I assume it is correct. However, I still cannot make my command work. See the question edit.

Comment: I don't see any edit in the question. The question is: is your variable V2 continuous or factor? If you want to treat it as continous, change it to numeric (if numbers): `data$V2<-as.numeric(as.character(data$V2))` ( I am assuming that there are no NA.s

Comment: Now edited. It was factor so I changed to date-time, still doesn't work.

Comment: Ok. I think this is now a more statistical question. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I have a dataframe of transactions over the course of a day: one variable of their time and one variable of their amount. I then made a third variable of cumulative sales via cumsum. I want to plot and model this cumulative sales variable against the time of transaction.